# What is android:contextClickable in View for and what are context click events?

Tags: android, android-view

I stumbled upon the [`android:contextClickable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:contextClickable) property inside the `View` class, and the documentation is not very clear on that:

> Defines whether this view reacts to context click events.

What is a "context click event"? When is this property useful? Googling didn't yield any meaningful information on the subject.

Comment: I suspect that this refers to a right-mouse click, though I just ran across this stuff a few days ago myself and haven't run any tests yet.

Comment: Indeed, it's only been introduced in API 23. Thanks @CommonsWare, will follow your blog in case you run across this feature in your research.